# HockeyApp crash, forked Queues, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, hockeyapp

Using someone else's framework from GitHub for a UIButton Process effect.
Works fine when installed through latest XCode, but app crashes as soon as button starts animation, if installed through HockeyApp.
Here is the Animation Function in question:

```
  private func startAnimating() {
    isAnimating = true
    views = []

    for i in 0..<colors.count {
        let view = UIView(frame: lineRect())
        view.backgroundColor = colors[i]
        views.append(view)
    }

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

        var count: Int = 0
        while self.isAnimating {
            if count == self.views.count {
                count = 0
            }

            var next = false
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                UIView.animateWithDuration(self.duration, delay: 0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
                    if self.isAnimating {

                        if !self.views.isEmpty {
                        self.addSubview(self.views[count])
                        self.views[count].frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: 0)
                        self.views[count].frame.size.width = self.frame.width
                        }
                    }
                    }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                        if self.isAnimating {
                            var lastIndex = count - 1
                            if lastIndex < 0 {
                                lastIndex = self.colors.count - 1
                            }
                            self.views[lastIndex].frame = self.lineRect()
                            self.views[lastIndex].removeFromSuperview()
                        }
                        next = true
                })
            })

            // Let's wait until the current animation is done before moving forward
            while !next {
            }
            count++
        }
    })

}
```

HockeyApp points to the first reference of 'views' inside the second Queue, which in this case is the empty check ( I've added that, but if not there it will point to the next reference ) :

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(self.duration, delay: 0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
                        if self.isAnimating {

                            if !self.views.isEmpty {
                            self.addSubview(self.views[count])
                            self.views[count].frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: 0)
                            self.views[count].frame.size.width = self.frame.width
                            }
                        }
```

Here is the key piece of the HockeyApp's crash report:

```
Date/Time:       2016-02-03T18:01:01Z
Launch Time:     2016-02-03T18:00:33Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x100099080
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
Selector name found in current argument registers: release

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   barscan1                             0x0000000100099080 barscan1.ProcessView.((startAnimating in _126B4789AED4AC2C363037724C3D4FEF) (barscan1.ProcessView) -> () -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1).(closure #1) (ProcessView.swift:78)
1   UIKit                                0x0000000185eb8210 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 616
2   UIKit                                0x0000000185ecfc58 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 104
3   barscan1                             0x0000000100098d90 barscan1.ProcessView.((startAnimating in _126B4789AED4AC2C363037724C3D4FEF) (barscan1.ProcessView) -> () -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1) (ProcessView.swift:94)
4   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000180be1630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
5   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000180be15f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000180be6cf8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1840
7   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181144bb0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
8   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181142a18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1624
9   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000181071680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380
10  GraphicsServices                     0x0000000182580088 GSEventRunModal + 176
11  UIKit                                0x0000000185ee8d90 UIApplicationMain + 200
12  barscan1                             0x00000001000aa32c main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
13  ???                                  0x0000000180c128b8 0x0 + 0
```

Any help is greatly appreciated ! 
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Turned out this is a problem with Apple's Swift Optimization - set it to NONE and now the problem is gone.

Comment: Just be aware that you shouldn't disable those optimizations permanently as they could significantly slow down your code. If you can, please also file a bug with Apple so they can better work on a fix.